# Comparison of variances

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, hypothesis-testing, variance

Imagine the situation having 10 groups of observed data. Your main aim is to know if the variances of all groups are equal or there is at least one pair of groups with different variances. So the null hypothesis is

$H0: σ_1 = σ_2 = ... = σ_{10}$.

Which test is the best for assessing the equality of variances in this situation? Is there need to use the multiple testing corrections?